# send SMS with schedule to third party SMS company in outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I use SMS from scheduler in Outlook as reminder to myclients. I send it to third party Company that sedi to client at the date i´w set in Outlook. This funktion is removed in Outlook 2010. Is it possible to get it back?
/Bertil

Comment: Please provide more information.  For instance what feature exactly do you believe to have been removed from Outlook 2010?